# Match anything except for the character selected by the group previously

Tags: c#, regex

I have this regular expression:

```
(?=(([a-z]{1})([a-z]{1})\2))
```

Through which I am trying to fetch all the palindromic strings. So, if this is my string:

```
mnonopooo
```

My regular expression does select all the palindromic strings in the string but it selects `ooo` also and I know the reason, it is because of this center part of my regular expression:

```
(?=(([a-z]{1})     "([a-z]{1})"        \2))
```

This part should be like this, match everything except for the backreference group `\2`.

So I tried something like this, but it didn't work:

```
(?=(([a-z]{1})     (?!\2)       \2))
```

So basically, my regular expression has three parts:

1. Select any single character (This is working)
2. Match any single character not equal to the character matched in point 1 (Not working)
3. Select the same character that is matched in point 1 (Working using backreference)

So, the second part I am not able to make. 
Can anybody please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a negative Lookahead (i.e., `(?!\2)`) to make sure the first matched letter is not repeated and keep the 3rd group as is (you still need it):

```
(?=(([a-z])(?!\2)([a-z])\2))
```

Please note that the usage of `{1}` is redundant so I removed them.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/BVvwnp/1

Comment: Great! Thanks!! It worked. Could you please also tell me if I want it to select not only one single character but multiple same characters so it can select this also `ooonooo`

Comment: Just add a `+` inside the 2nd capturing group: [`(?=(([a-z]+)(?!\2)([a-z])\2))`](https://regex101.com/r/BVvwnp/2). Note that this will match `ono`, `oonoo`, and `ooonooo` out of the example you provided.

Comment: Great! Thanks :)

Comment: But this `+` will select not only `oonoo` but will also match `aonao` because we are not forcing the group to select same character

Comment: You're right, my bad! You can use [`(?=((([a-z])\3*)(?!\2)([a-z])\2))`](https://regex101.com/r/BVvwnp/3) instead. Also, note that there's no reason to put the last `[a-z]` in a capturing group _unless you need it for something_.